# Transfer xml element content to another set of elements using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am attempting to copy the content from one set of sibling elements to a set of like elements located within the same document that have different parent and ancestor elements.

I would think this would be easy using the key function, but all the examples I find online and in my xslt cookbook reference matching attributes and not elements.

I have been researching this for hours and am extremely frustrated. I am fairly new to xml and xslt.

note- The example below represents an example of what I'm trying to accomplish in principal. The actual document I'm working with has over 50 sibling data elements with associated content. Apologize for not having picture (reputation is not high enough).

### starting xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<DE>
  <set1>
    <Type>
      <Thing>
        <title></title>
        <year></year>
        <Author></Author>
        <Store></Store>
      </Thing>
    </Type>
  </set1>

  <record>
    <title>WorkPlease</title>
    <year>2012</year>
    <Author>Jimmy</Author>
    <Store>ArmyStore</Store>
  </record>

</DE>
```

---

Desired End State

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

 <DE>
  <set1>
    <Type>
      <Thing>
        <title>WorkPlease</title>
        <year>2012</year>
        <Author>Jimmy</Author>
        <Store>ArmyStore</Store>
      </Thing>
    </Type>
  </set1>

  <record>
    <title>WorkPlease</title>
    <year>2012</year>
    <Author>Jimmy</Author>
    <Store>ArmyStore</Store>
  </record>

</DE>
```

Comment: I think there are some important details missing from this example.  Do you always want to replace the contents of `set1/Type/Thing` with the contents of the following `record`, or is it more involved than that?  Could you give an example of what a few more records might look like?

Comment: Now that I think I understand what the xslt code is doing it may be a little more involved. For some of the data I am populating the sibling relationship is 1 to 1. However there are also cases where there are like and unlike siblings that I am attemptign to populate with contents. An example above would be if the "thing" element had 3 additional siblings (i.e. genre, coauthor, and publisher) that I wanted to maintain data fields for but not populate with "record" element.

Answer (score 0):

Use a following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/DE">
    <DE>
      <!-- 'set1' contents -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="record" mode="sets" />

      <!-- 'record' contents -->
      <xsl:apply-templates select="record" />
    </DE>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record">
    <!-- copy 'record' tag along with it's children -->
    <xsl:copy-of select="." />
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="record" mode="sets">
    <set1>
      <Type>
        <Thing>
          <!-- copy 'record' tag's children without the 'record' tag itself -->
          <xsl:copy-of select="node()" />
        </Thing>
      </Type>
    </set1>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you very much...that is EXACTLY what I was trying to do.

Comment: I'm glad it helped. Can you mark your question as solved? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

the solution from @kamituel is far more advanced but may be this snippet will help you to understand how xslt works

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="xml" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="record">
    <xsl:element name="DE">
      <xsl:element name="set1">
        <xsl:element name="Type">
          <xsl:element name="Thing">
            <xsl:call-template name="copy-attributes"/>
          </xsl:element>
        </xsl:element>
      </xsl:element>
    <xsl:call-template name="create-record"/>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="copy-attributes">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="create-record">
    <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you ...I was having some trouble correlating the element paths to my actual working document, and now for some reason Eclipse won't perform the xslt transformation, no errors or anything just nothing happens after I select input file. Its going to be a long morning:) Thanks again.

Comment: Off topic, but to anyone else reading this that had a similiar issue with eclipse. Clearing out launch configurators in elcipse solved the issue with running xslt. Right click .xsl file in project exlorer menu  - select Run As - Run Configurations ---once Run Configurations menu opens delete the configurations under xsl in left menu. There is probably a beter way to do it but this worked for me.